# Sparse matrix with filled row and diagonal

Tags: python, matrix, scipy, sparse-matrix

I have a sparse matrix that I am constructing using several diagonals:

```
A = diags([np.arange(100), np.arange(99), np.arange(99)], offsets=[0, -1, 1])
```

However, this sparse matrix also has a vector of ones in the last row. Is there any way to store this in the sparse matrix or is my construct to inefficient and I should work with a dense matrix?

Comment: What makes you think you can't store it?

Comment: @PeterWood I could imagine that sparse matrices are optimized for containing either row, column or diagonal information, and once one starts to cross these with each other the memory gained from sparse storage becomes negligible - and therefore not being supported by `scipy`

Comment: Is the last row really necessary to have in the sparse array? You could just insert the sum of the vector you're multiplying by into the last entry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sparse.diags` does make a sparse matrix with a special `diagonal` format:

```
In [591]: A = sparse.diags([np.arange(100), np.arange(99), np.arange(99)], offse
     ...: ts=[0, -1, 1])
In [592]: A
Out[592]: 
<100x100 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 298 stored elements (3 diagonals) in DIAgonal format>
In [593]: A.A
Out[593]: 
array([[  0.,   0.,   0., ...,   0.,   0.,   0.],
       [  0.,   1.,   1., ...,   0.,   0.,   0.],
       [  0.,   1.,   2., ...,   0.,   0.,   0.],
       ..., 
       [  0.,   0.,   0., ...,  97.,  97.,   0.],
       [  0.,   0.,   0., ...,  97.,  98.,  98.],
       [  0.,   0.,   0., ...,   0.,  98.,  99.]])
```

But the storage isn't significantly more efficient than other sparse formats.  Other formats have to store the same 298 values.  They'll just index them differently.

We can set the last row in various ways.

We can't index the last row directly with the sparse format.

```
In [594]: A[-1,:]
...
TypeError: 'dia_matrix' object is not subscriptable
```

but we can convert it to `csr` format, and set its row value:

```
In [595]: A.tocsr()[-1,:]
Out[595]: 
<1x100 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 2 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
In [596]: Ac = A.tocsr()
In [597]: Ac[-1,:]=1
/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/scipy/sparse/compressed.py:730: SparseEfficiencyWarning: Changing the sparsity structure of a csr_matrix is expensive.
In [598]: Ac
Out[598]: 
<100x100 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 393 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
In [599]: Ac.A
Out[599]: 
array([[  0.,   0.,   0., ...,   0.,   0.,   0.],
       [  0.,   1.,   1., ...,   0.,   0.,   0.],
       [  0.,   1.,   2., ...,   0.,   0.,   0.],
       ..., 
       [  0.,   0.,   0., ...,  97.,  97.,   0.],
       [  0.,   0.,   0., ...,  97.,  98.,  98.],
       [  1.,   1.,   1., ...,   1.,   1.,   1.]])
```

Here I wouldn't worry about the sparsity warning; that's meant more for cases where the action is done iteratively.  I could have used `tolil()` instead.  Keep in mind that the `csr` format gets use for calculations.  And the `coo` format is use when combining blocks of matrices.

---

I just checked the `sparse.dia_matrix` code.  For your array `A.data` is a (3,100) array.  It 'squared off' your ragged input.  `A.offsets` is a 3 element array.

`A.tocoo()` stores the values in 3 (295,) arrays  (removing the 3 0's in your definition).  A `A.tocsr()` stores 2 (295,) arrays plus a (101,) `indptr` array.  So the `dia` format is more compact, but only so long as you can work in the format.

---

To append the ones row instead, use `sparse.vstack` (`vstack` uses `coo` format to construct the new matrix):

```
In [619]: B = sparse.vstack((A,np.ones((1,100))))
In [620]: B
Out[620]: 
<101x100 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 395 stored elements in COOrdinate format>
```

Out of curiosity I tried `vstack` with a `dia` output - it doesn't like it, because the squared off `dia` data would be too large.

```
In [621]: B = sparse.vstack((A,np.ones((1,100))),format='dia')
/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/scipy/sparse/coo.py:359: SparseEfficiencyWarning: Constructing a DIA matrix with 102 diagonals is inefficient
```

Assignment with the `lil` format doesn't produce any warnings:

```
In [624]: Al = A.tolil()
In [625]: Al[-1,:]=1
In [626]: Al
Out[626]: 
<100x100 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 393 stored elements in LInked List format>
```

This too is converted to `csr` for most calculations.